# Rotating vectors with transformations

Tags: calculus, matrices, trigonometry, vectors, rotations

Let $θ_0$ be a real number. Define $R : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$R(x, y) = ((cos θ_0)x − (sin θ_0)y,(sin θ_0)x + (cos θ_0)y)$.

How do I show that $R$ rotates both $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ by the angle $θ_0$ counterclockwise? I know that $R$ should be a linear transformation

Comment: $R({\bf{i}})=R(1,0)=(\cos\theta_0, \sin\theta_0)$ and ...

Comment: and i assume the ... is to show for j = (0,1). So if I wanna show the linear transformation R as a 2x2 matrix, it would be [cos, sin ; -sin, cos]?

Answer (score 1):

The image of the vector $\mathbf i=(1,0)$ is $(\cos \theta_0, \sin \theta_0)$. The inner product of this last vector with vector $\mathbf i$ equals $\cos \theta_0$. And the cross product $\sin\theta_0$. This gives the conclusion for $\mathbf i$.

You can do a similar analysis for $\mathbf j$.

Comment: if I wanna show the linear transformation R as a 2x2 matrix, it would be [cos, sin ; -sin, cos]?

Comment: For sure, by definition of the matrix of a linear transformation.

Comment: The matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix},$ isn't it?

Comment: @mfl Yes this is the matrix. I interpreted the comment of user3427042 as the matrix written by columns.

Comment: ya thats what I meant sorry, tried to write in MATLAB way but got dyslexic lol